# Animate UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uitableview

I've got a question regarding animating a UITableViewCell.

I want to have it so that the UITableViewCell animates right (much like the UINavigationController animations), revealing a seperate view, allowing the user to perform different tasks.

But I'm not sure if I animate its contentView, or replace the cell entirely.

I tried using UIView animations, but they don't work.

I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom `UITableViewCell` which has 2 UIViews in it. Then you can animate them by setting their frame's `x` value.